# What is the difference between \newline and \\?

Tags: line-breaking

As far as I know, `\\` and `\newline` both insert a new line. But they do not have an identical expansion and tracing shows they do not execute the same commands, so what is their difference?

Comment: As far as I know, `\newline` is defined as the normal (i.e., without optional argument and non-starred) version of \\.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Yip, from [`latex.ltx1`](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx), `\DeclareRobustCommand\newline{\@normalcr\relax}` where `expandafter\let\expandafter\@normalcr \csname\expandafter\@gobble\string\\ \endcsname`.

Comment: Don't also forget the \linebreak command

Comment: Doesn't `\newline` mark the division between paragraphs?

Comment: See also: [paragraphs - When to use \par and when \\, \newline, or blank lines - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

From a usage point-of-view, there is a difference between `\\` and `\newline`:

- [`\\`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-181.html)

  Tells LaTeX to start a new line. This command has a starred version and takes an optional parameter:

  - `\\*`: Similar to `\\` but also tells LaTeX not to start a new page after the line by issuing a `\nobreak`.
  - `\\[<len>]`: This specifies the vertical space `<len>` to be inserted before the next line. Can also be negative.

  The above two can also be mixed. That is, using both a starred + optional argument combination `\\*[<len>]`.
- [`\newline`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-275.html)

  Same as `\\`, but does not take a star.

From a technical point of view (in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)), these commands are defined as follows, justifying the similarity between `\\` (unstarred and without optional argument) and `\newline`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\\{%
  \let \reserved@e \relax
  \let \reserved@f \relax
  \@ifstar{\let \reserved@e \vadjust \let \reserved@f \nobreak \@xnewline}%
  \@xnewline}
\expandafter\let\expandafter\@normalcr
  \csname\expandafter\@gobble\string\\ \endcsname
\DeclareRobustCommand\newline{\@normalcr\relax}
```

LaTeX also redefines `\\` to mean other things depending on the environment(s) you use. For example, within an `array` or `tabular` environment, the commonly-used `\\` has a slightly different meaning to when it is used in regular text.

Comment: Note that \\ will be redefined by some commands like `\centering` while `\newline` won't. For that reason using `\newline` with `\centering` will give undesired results.

Comment: Can you give an example of `\\*[<len>]` which skips 2 baselines?

Comment: For someone who is new to Latex, your answer reads as: "From a usage POV, there is a difference between A and B: A does something, and B is similar to A. From a technical POV: [Don't understand a word]". Maybe you could add an example of different behavior in common text formatting situations?

Comment: I don't understand the answer. "\\ tells ...., \newline Similar to \\". So is there a difference between the two or not? What's the difference? Is there an example where the two commands can give different results?

Comment: @gigabytes: As mentioned in [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/what-is-the-difference-between-newline-and/27040?noredirect=1#comment52835_27040), `\centering` would be one case where ``\\`` and `\newline` would yield different results. See [this paste](http://pastebin.com/JPVQ8acj) and [its accompanying output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyDjK.png).

Comment: I think the point of "similar to `\\ `" is that it's not starred and not using the optional argument.  So a regular `\\ ` would be similar to `\newline`, but `\\*` and `\\[length]` would not be similar.

Comment: I am gonna be franc: an answer that is meant to explain the difference between A and B, talks about what A does and says that B "is similar" to A **is not an answer**. Everyone landing here *knows* that they are similar, but they wanna know the **difference**. Your answer is merely stating the obvious. Having that said, seeing the technical part provided, I have confidence that you *are* able to explain the actual differences and would be very keen and grateful to read that.

Comment: @Mayou36: What you're missing here is subtle. `\newline` is similar to ``\\`` in the sense that it calls ``\\`` without the `*` (optional) or `[<len>]` optional arguments. Instead, it's similar to ``\\\relax``.

Comment: @Werner perfect! But let me claim that not I am missing it, but the **answer** is missing this. Most notably, "similar" or "same except"? Similar really should not be used here, we're all aware that it's similar. I'd expect to see that "they are the same *except the following differences*. From your answer, is `\newline` the **same** as `\\` without any arguments?  It's "similar" according to the answer, but what does that mean?