# Multiple subtitle

Tags: titles

I am new to latex. This is my document. And my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Symplectic Geometry in Classical Mechanics}

\author{}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{Lecture 1}
\chapter{Basics of Manifolds}\\*
It is a mathematical formalism underlying\\*
\begin{itemize}\\*
\item Geometrical Optics\\  
\item Classical Mechanics\\
\item General Relativity\\
\item Quantum Mechanics\\
\end{itemize}

Such a unifying formalism help us to solve problems in one area of physics
by using ideas from another areas.
It doesn't work for systems with loss, friction or noise.

\end{document}
```

Actually I want three titles in this document.

First - "Symplectic Geometry in Classical Mechanics"

Second - "Lecture 1"

Third - "Basics of Manifolds"

I want all the three to be in different lines at the centre. But the above code is not giving it properly. How to do it?

Comment: There's no `\chapter` in the `article` class. It can't compile.

Comment: Furthermore your use of `\\*` seems quite strange. You should simply remove them.

Comment: Then what class should I choose for writing lecture notes. Also if I want to go to next line, then what should I use instead of \\*.

Comment: You can find some useful information on how to start a new line here: [When to use \par and when \\, or blank lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664/134144) and  here: [What does \\* do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55470/134144)

Comment: You'll probably want to use `book` or `report` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36988/156366)). You should rarely have to explicitly tell LaTeX to skip to the next line because it automatically begins things like chapter titles, `itemize` items etc. on separate lines. Note that paragraphs should be sepaparted by an empty line (or a `\par`).

Comment: Friendly advice: Maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11 (*What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?*) before you start a fairly complex/big document with only little LaTeX knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own `subtitle` and `subsubtitle` commands with the help of the `titling` package as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\Large#1\end{center}
   }%
}



\newcommand{\subsubtitle}[1]{%
  \preauthor{%
    \begin{center}
    \large #1 \vskip0.5em
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    }%
}


\title{Symplectic Geometry in Classical Mechanics }
\subtitle{Lecture 1}
\subsubtitle{Basics of Manifolds}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

It is a mathematical formalism underlying
\begin{itemize}
\item Geometrical Optics  
\item Classical Mechanics
\item General Relativity
\item Quantum Mechanics
\end{itemize}

Such a unifying formalism help us to solve problems in one area of physics
by using ideas from another areas.
It doesn't work for systems with loss, friction or noise.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To remove the white space below the subtitle (that is 'reserved'  for author and date, you could use the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\Large#1\end{center}
   }%
}



\newcommand{\subsubtitle}[1]{%
  \preauthor{%
    \begin{center}
    \large #1 \vskip0.5em
    %\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    }%
}
  \postauthor{%
    \end{center}
    }%
\predate{}
\postdate{}

\title{Symplectic Geometry in Classical Mechanics }
\subtitle{Lecture 1}
\subsubtitle{Basics of Manifolds}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

It is a mathematical formalism underlying
\begin{itemize}
\item Geometrical Optics  
\item Classical Mechanics
\item General Relativity
\item Quantum Mechanics
\end{itemize}

Such a unifying formalism help us to solve problems in one area of physics
by using ideas from another areas.
It doesn't work for systems with loss, friction or noise.

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more 'quick and dirty'  approach would be the following example, where is used `\author` for the subtitle and `\date` for the subsubtitle:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\title{Symplectic Geometry in Classical Mechanics }
\author{Lecture 1}
\date{Basics of Manifolds}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

It is a mathematical formalism underlying
\begin{itemize}
\item Geometrical Optics  
\item Classical Mechanics
\item General Relativity
\item Quantum Mechanics
\end{itemize}

Such a unifying formalism help us to solve problems in one area of physics
by using ideas from another areas.
It doesn't work for systems with loss, friction or noise.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is to much space between basics of manifolds and the starting sentence. Is there a way to reduce it.

Comment: @Khushal: This white space is kind of reserved for the author and date. Do you want to use them in your actual document?

Comment: Yeah but what if I don't want to put author's name and date, can't I just remove that space?

Comment: @Khushal: I have edited my answer to include two different possibilities on how to remove the white space between the subsubtitle and the first line of text.

Answer (score 3):

A variant with `\maketitlehookb` from `titling`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{Symplectic Geometry in Classical Mechanics}

\author{I. Ego}

\date{\today}

\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
\gdef\subT{#1}}
\newcommand{\subT}{}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{%
\par\Large\centering\noindent \subT}
\subtitle{Lecture1\\[1ex] Basics of Manifolds\vskip 2em}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

It is a mathematical formalism underlying%\\*
\begin{itemize}%\\*
\item Geometrical Optics%\\
\item Classical Mechanics%\\
\item General Relativity%\\
\item Quantum Mechanics%\\
\end{itemize}

Such a unifying formalism help us to solve problems in one area of physics
by using ideas from another areas.
It doesn't work for systems with loss, friction or noise.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I have to add a heading before the paragraph? The heading is " Why Symplectic Geometry?"? Do I have to insert it as a title or should I put it in the body?

Comment: You mean a heading, not a section title? Centred too?

Comment: Actually a section title. It should be on the left.