# Difference between \\ and \tabularnewline

Tags: tables, line-breaking

What is the difference between `\\` and `\tabularnewline`? 
Is it same as the [difference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/what-is-the-difference-between-newline-and) between `\\` and `newline`?

Is `\tabularnewline` preferred over `\\` when creating tables?

Comment: Which package (if any) are you using for tabular material?

Comment: @percusse I was wondering about the difference after seeing some questions and answers posted here. I tried searching for `tabularnewline` but it gave me lot of results, but wasn't able to find the difference.

Comment: No problem. As David mentioned, the doublebackslashes are redefined a lot so I was trying to narrow down the focus if it was specifically about one implementation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If your `tabular` contains `p`-columns, then there is a ambiguity: Does `\\` should end a line inside a cell or should it end a tabular row? The use of `\newline` and `\tabularnewline` make that clear, the first ends the line in a cell, the latter the row of the table.

See also `\arraybackslash` of package `array` that can be used to reset the meaning of `\\` to be `\tabularnewline`, from the documentation:

> `\arraybackslash`: Restore `\\` for use in array and tabular
>   environment    (after `\raggedright` etc.).
>
> ```
> \def\arraybackslash{\let\\\tabularnewline}
> ```

Comment: +1 Heiko beat me by 30 seconds:-) so the main point is that `\\` has _many_ definitions in latex: in tables, in normal text in centering etc it is locally defined to whatever needs doing.

Comment: In my limited usage I have always seen `\\` end tabular row. So is `\tabularnewline` for clarity for the user? (If it matters I usually use `memoir` and `article` document)