# longtable with booktabs, midrule is pushed to next page

Tags: tables, longtable, booktabs

I'd like to make a formal longtable in landscape mode. I use booktabs to make the table formal.
Here is an example tex document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\begin{landscape} \sffamily{%
\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{7cm}>{\centering}p{7cm}}
\toprule 
Header & \\
\midrule
\endhead
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}}\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

When the document is compiled (pdflatex) the rule (midrule) below the last row (row 10) on page 2 is pushed to the next page, which results in double lines below the header row. Why is this and how could it be fixed?

Edit:

Here's another example, a little bit more complex table which has first header, header, footer and last footer, and shows similar problem. How can I fix this one?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]

\begin{landscape} \sffamily{%
\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{7cm}>{\centering}p{7cm}}
\toprule 
First Header & \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Header & \\
\midrule
\endhead
Footer & \\
\midrule
\endfoot
Last Footer & \\
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\
\midrule
\end{longtable}}\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You've edited the question, and the solution in my answer works in all cases.

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, thanks. I edited my question because first there were two other answers which were removed in the meantime. One of the answers solved the first example but not the second one.

Comment: Note that the recommendation is to use `\bottomrule` in `\endfoot` and remove unnecessary `\midrule` or `\cmidrule{}` commands manually. That is, this is what `booktabs` suggests.

Comment: @karlkoeller Sorry, I clicked the wrong button. If I use \\* I occasionally get error message: ! Misplaced \noalign. I found that I have to use tabularnewline to fix this. I tried tabularnewline* and it works but I cannot find any reference to it. Could you please give a link to a reference on tabularnewline?

Comment: @bcsikos Using `\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{7cm} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{7cm}}` you should be able to use ``\\*`` without problems. Anyway, here is the link you've requested: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78796/27635

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `\\*` instead of `\\`. In this way `\midrule`s are kept together with their row.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\begin{landscape} \sffamily{%
\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{7cm}>{\centering}p{7cm}}
\toprule
Header & \\
\midrule
\endhead
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\midrule
\blindtext[2] & \\*
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}}\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]