# Longtable last page shows only a table header and bottom line

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape

> I Updated the MWE to address comments by David. Now I am using a CSV-file ('unknown number of records'). This give the same 'header-only/bottom line' (tested in Overleaf) on page last page. **How to get this always working nicely (independent of number of records)?**

I have a problem with longtable. A longtable sometimes produces an "empty" last table page (that is only a header and a bottom line, so no data lines).

(credits) I changed the MWE of [this tex.stackexchange.com post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231673/longtable-with-booktabs-midrule-is-pushed-to-next-page) to demonstrate the problem.

More in general: how can I get the longtable behaviour: **"if the remaining number of records is less than x skip them to the next page even if the current page is not full"**.  So then I can say do the last [2,3,4 or 5] (and total count is higher else we are in an endless loop) on a new page to avoid I get a ugly 1 item table on the last page.

**MWE Last page screenshot (Overleaf generated):**

[image]

**MWE Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{demo.csv}
col
a 
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
z1 
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.03}
\blindtext[5]
\begin{landscape}  
\DTLloaddb{dset}{demo.csv}
\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{7cm}>{\centering}p{7cm}}
\toprule 
Header & \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\DTLforeach*{dset}{\COL=col}%
{\COL & t\tabularnewline}%
\end{longtable}\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The posted code does not show the problem, and has a last row with Jack... as well as the header on the final page 3, but as documented in the longtable manual to keep rows together you can use `\\*` or (more strongly) put  more rows into the `\endlastfoot` section. Also note that `\sfamily` does not take an argument so you should remove the `{}` group around the table.

Note that the issue of a final break at a rule is more likely with `booktabs` rules as they, by design, have vertical space around them, and in `longtable` this introduces additional breakpoints.

Comment: Ok, I made a more advanced MWE, now with CSV-file/datatool. I still get this empty header/footer on the last page. How to get this always working nicely independent of the number of records?

Comment: @robert that's rather changed the question as the standard longtable answer to ensuring that at least (say) 5 rows stay on the last page is to put them in the `\endlasthead` but the new question is not really about longtable at all it's about datatool and whether it can do that (which I don't know, offhand.

Comment: OK, thanks for your contribution. The real question relates to datatool/longtable with empty header/footer.  So beside taking an another MWE with errors (`sfamily`) and change that, I updated it to reflect my real issue.

Answer (score 0):

> **DataTool/LongTable best practice here!!**

I found the issue. If you experience this issue, you need to make the following changes. Background is that the original MWE is always emiting a `\tabularnewline` after each row, also the last one. In the new approach this is outputed before the start of a new row (with exception of the first row).

**Never use (as in MWE):**

```
\DTLforeach*{dset}{\COL=col}%
{\COL & t\tabularnewline}%
```

**But use:**

```
\DTLforeach*{dset}{\COL=col}%
{\DTLiffirstrow{}{\tabularnewline}%
\COL & t}%
```