# Tables with centered columns of specific width?

Tags: tables

I like it when tables have centered columns (e.g. `|c|c|c|`).

However, I have width restrictions. The most obvious solution to force a table to be within a certain width is to do `|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|`, etc. However, this puts the text off to one side instead of centered.

**Ideally**, I'd like to say "my table will be a total of 10cm wide" and "the columns will be centered." Is there a way to do this?

**Next best thing**, can I make a table where I specify each column's width, and the columns are centered?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways you can achieve what you want. The first is as in Maarten's answer, which requires you to specify the width of each column.  The use of `\arraybackslash` is needed in case the centred column is the last column in the table.  See the `array` package documentation for more information on this or [Difference between \\ and \tabularnewline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78796/2693).

A second way is to use the `tabulary` package, which allows you to define columns that will fill up the maximum width of the table.  Here's an example of both. I've used `K` as the column type to distinguish it from the C column type defined within the `tabulary` environment.

Please note that I've used `\hline` in the example code just to show the width of the tables. For most tables I would highly recommend the `booktabs` package, and its various rule commands which have much better spacing and width parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
table with centred columns of specified width
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{K{2cm}K{2cm}}
\hline
foo & bar \\
foobar & barfoo \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

table of 5cm width, centred columns
\bigskip

\begin{tabulary}{5cm}{CC}
\hline
foo & bar \\
foobar & barfoo\\
A much wider column  & c \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\bigskip

as we make the total width wider, the columns adjust
\bigskip

\begin{tabulary}{8cm}{CC}
\hline
foo & bar \\
foobar & barfoo\\
A much wider column  & c \\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I ended up using `tabulary` -- it works great. The other responses look good, too.

Answer (score 9):

> When I posted this, I did not realise that Mico had posted an [answer
>   using `tabularx`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238025/) 3 minutes
>   earlier than I hit the `submit` button. So credit for the use of
>   [tabularx](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) should go to Mico.
>
> I am leaving this answer, with Mico's approval, because it also
>   demonstrates the advantages of using
>   [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to create nicer horizontal
>   rules and dispensing with vertical rules. This enables you to produce
>   professional quality tables. For more information, take a look at the
>   [booktabs
>   manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf)
>   which provides lots of advice about presenting information effectively
>   in tabulars. (The manual is also available in
>   [French](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/translations/booktabs/fr/f-booktabs.pdf)
>   and
>   [German](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs-de/booktabs-de.pdf).)

For completeness, here is a solution which combines `tabularx` with `booktabs`.

As Mico explains, `tabularx` allows you to specify the total width of the table. At least one of your columns must then be `X` which expands to fill the width. In this case, I use `array` to define a centred version of this column type, `C` and specify 3 such columns for the table.

`booktabs` provides enhanced spacing and additional commands for drawing horizontal rules. In a professional quality table, the top and bottom rules should be heavier than rules within the table. Consequently, `booktabs` provides `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` as demonstrated below. For additional possibilities, including `\cmidrule` and rule trimming, see the excellent package documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{3}{C}}
    \toprule
    Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3\\\midrule
    This is some text which will be longer than the width of the column. & This is some more text which will be longer than the width of this second column. & And here is some more text for the third column.\\\bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: set width tabular]

Comment: @Mico Missed that. Should I delete this? I'm only tempted to leave it because I used `booktabs`. If you don't want me to delete, I'll add a note at the top pointing to your answer as the first one. Otherwise, I'd be happy to delete if you wouldn't mind mentioning `booktabs`?

Answer (score 6):

You wrote,

> **Ideally,** I'd like to say "my table will be a total of 10cm wide" and "the columns will be centered." Is there a way to do this?

Answer: Yes -- with the help of the `tabularx` package, which provides the `tabularx` environment that lets you specify the overall width of the tabular-like structure, and the `array` package, which lets you modify `tabularx`'s `X` column-type to typeset the contents centered rather than fully justified. (I'm assuming here that you want all columns to be equally wide.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % also loads 'array' package
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X' columns
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{|C|C|C|}
\hline
some text & more text & a huge amount of additional text\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Note that if (i) the total width of the `tabularx` is given by `totalwidth`, (ii) there are `n` columns, and (iii) each column is delimited by vertical bars (hence, `n+1` vertical bars in total), the *usable width* of each column is equal to

```
(totalwidth-2*n*\tabcolsep-(n+1)*\arrayrulewidth)/n
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `array` package you can specify new column types:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|C{1cm}|C{3cm}|C{1cm}|}
    \dots & \dots & \dots
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or simply change  `|p{2.5cm}|` by `|>{\centering}p{2.5cm}|`