# missing $ inserted resizebox

Tags: tables, math-mode

[image]

I have some problem with resizebox

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.9pt,two column]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\graphicspath{{pictures/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} %колонтитул
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{132} 
\fancyhead[R]{К.Д. Демаков, В.А. Старостин, С.Г. Шемардов}
\fancyfoot[R]{Журнал технической физики,2002, том 72, вып.10} 

\begin{document}
\parindent=0cm
ника не дает решения с максимумом, расположенным дальше пробега ионов источника от границы.Важным моментом модели является ее неравновесность~-— диффузия просиходит на фоне интенсивного рождения и аннигиляции дефектов. Эти процессы описываются следующей системой связанных уравнений:

$${\partial n_{a}}\!/{\partial t} =D_{a} {\partial^2 n_{a}}\!/{\partial x^{2}} - n_{a} n_{v} k_{cap} + n_{c} n_{d} k_{act}$$
\begin{equation}
+j_{0exp}(-{R_{p}-x+x_{0}}^{2}/2\Delta{{R_{p}}^{2}})/\sqrt{2}\pi \Delta {R_{p}},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{\partial n_{c}}\!/{\partial t}= n_{a} n_{v} k_{cap} - n_c n_{d} k_{act} , 
\end{equation}

$$ {\partial n_{d}}\!/{\partial t}=D_{dV} {\partial^{2} n_{d}\!/{\partial x^{2}}-n_{c} n_{d} - k_{act}} $$

\begin{equation}
-n_{V} n_{d} k_{ann} + j_{0} N \sigma_{d} \Theta(R_{p}-x+ x_{0}),
\end{equation}

$${\partial n_{V}}\!/{\partial t}= D_{dV} {\partial^{2} n_{d}}\!/{\partial x^{2}}- n_{a} n_{V} - k_{cap} $$

$$
- n_{V} n_{d} k_{ann} + j_{0} N \sigma_{d}\Theta(R_{p} -x+ x_{0}),$$

\qquad
$x_{0}$=-$v_{b}$t,\quad $N=5.04*10^{22} cm^{-3}$ ,

\begin{equation}
\sigma_d=3.52*10^{-16} cm^{2}
\end{equation}

где $\Theta(x)$ ~-— единичная ступенька; $N$ ~---плотность ядер кремния;$\sigma_{d}$ ~---ориентировачное сечение образования дефекта;$R_p$ и $\Delta{R}_{p}$ - пробег иона и его разброс; $D_{a}$,$D_{dV}$, $k_{cap}$, $k_{act}$,$k_{ann}$ -свободные параметры модели с очевидным физическим смыслом коэффициентов диффузии примеси и пар дефект ~— вакансий и скоростей квазихимических реакций захвата примеси вакансиями, активации примеси междоузлиями и взаимной аннигиляции вакансий и междоузолий соответственно.

\parindent=0.4cm
Условие на границе для примеси выбиралось нулевым исходя из эксперимента, что можно интерпретировать

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{arara.jpg}
\caption{Зависимость энтальпии миграции дефектов в кремнии от температурыпо данным табл. 2 и 4.}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{1}
\caption{Рассчитанные диффузионные коэффициенты и энтальпии} 
\hrule
\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
№ & D_{a},\frac{cm^2}{s}*10^{-11} & D_{dV},\frac{cm^{2}}{s}*10^{-11} & H_{dV}, cal/mol &T_{eff}, °K \\ \hline
1 & 0.169 & 0.204 & 64610 & 1326 &
2 & 0.540 & \hspace{5pt}0.0633 & 68151 & 1335& 
3 & 0.007 & \hspace{5pt}0.0463 & 47157 & \hspace{5pt}913&
4 & 0.499 & \hspace{5pt}0.0127 & 31937 & \hspace{5pt}589 &
\end{tabular} 

} 
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{2}
\caption{Рассчитанные скорости квазихимических реакций} 
\hrule
\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{c|с|с|c}
№ & K_{cap},\frac{cm^{3}}{s}*10^{-23} & K_{act},\frac{cm^{3}}{s}*10^{-23} & K_{ann},\frac{cm^{3}}{s}*10^{-23} \\ \hline
1 & 2.355 & 7.421 & 2.609 
2 & 0.889 & 8.321 & 5.795 
3 & 0.943 & 15.60 & 5.763 
4 & 0.929 & 8.260 & 5.855
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{3}
\caption{Рассчитанные энтальпии для других экспериментов}
\hrule
\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{с|с|с|с|с|с|с}
Ion & T,°C & j_{0}, \frac{\mu A}{cm^{2]} & K & T_{eff}, K & H_{dV}, cal/mol & Reference \\ \hline
Yb & 20 & 10 & 70 & 488 & 27811^* & [5,6] 
& & & & & 26877& 
& & & & & 24697& & 
Na & 365 & 0.3 & 7 & 638 & 35845
& [7] &
As & 20 & 150 & 25 & 722 & 38703 & [8] &
Tm & 500 & 30 & 150 & 906 & 50900 & [9] &
C & 20 & 300 & 40 & 961 & 46377^* & [2,10] &
& & & & & 46931& & 
& & & & & 47058& & 
As & 850 & 40 & 40 & 1143 & 57164 & [12] &
Tl & 1200 & 40 & 20 & 1478 & 70591 & [3] &
As & 1200 & 40 & 40 & 1482 & 74154 & [11] &
Tl & 1200 & 100 & 20 & 1484 & 70064 & [4]&
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}

как ее испарение с поверхности образца. Для междоузлий и вакансий использовалось такое условие, чтобы поток поток междоузлий вызывал смещение границы вещества со скоростью $V_b$ (задача типа Стефана). Начальные условия и условия на противоположной границе брались нулевые. Система уравнений (1)~-(4) при вышеописанных начальных и граничных условиях решалась численно на ЭВМ методом конечных разностей. Значения свободных параметров модели подбирались методом наименьших квадратов так, чтобы наилучшим образом соответствовать экспериментальным профилям.
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{1}
\caption{Рассчитанные диффузионные коэффициенты и энтальпии} 
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
№ & $D_{a}$,$\frac{cm^2}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $D_{dV}$,$\frac{cm^{2}}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $H_{dV}$, $cal/mol &T_{eff}, °K$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $0.169$ & $0.204$ & $64610$ & $1326$ &
$2$ & $0.540$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0633$ & $68151$ & 1335& 
$3$ & $0.007$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0463$ & $47157$ & \hspace{5pt}$913$ &
$4$ & $0.499$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0127$ & $31937 & \hspace{5pt}$589$ &

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{1}
\caption{Рассчитанные диффузионные коэффициенты и энтальпии} 
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
№ & $D_{a}$,$\frac{cm^2}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $D_{dV}$,$\frac{cm^{2}}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $H_{dV}$, $cal/mol &T_{eff}, °K$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $0.169$ & $0.204$ & $64610$ & $1326$ 
$2$ & $0.540$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0633$ & $68151$ & 1335&
$3$ & $0.007$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0463$ & $47157$ & \hspace{5pt}$913$ 
$4$ & $0.499$ & \hspace{5pt}$0.0127$ & $31937 & \hspace{5pt}$589$ 

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setcounter{table}{1}
\caption{Рассчитанные диффузионные коэффициенты и энтальпии} 
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}
{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
№ & $D_{a}$,$\frac{cm^2}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $D_{dV}$,$\frac{cm^{2}}{s}*10^{-11}$ & $H_{dV}$, $cal/mol &T_{eff}, °K$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $0.169$ & $0.204$ & $64610$ & $1326$ \\
$2$ & $0.540$ & $\hspace{5pt}0.0633$ & $68151$ & $1335$\\
$3$ & $0.007$ & $\hspace{5pt}0.0463$ & $47157$ & $\hspace{5pt}913$ \\
$4$ & $0.499$ & $\hspace{5pt}0.0127$ & $31937 & $\hspace{5pt}589$ \\

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
 №  & $D_{a}$,$\frac{cm^2}{s}*10^{-11}$
    & $D_{dV}$,$\frac{cm^{2}}{s}*10^{-11}$
    & $H_{dV}$, $cal/mol$
    & $T_{eff}, {}^\circ K$ \\
\hline
$1$ & $0.169$ & $0.204$ & $64610$ & $1326$ \\
$2$ & $0.540$ & $\hspace{5pt}0.0633$ & $68151$ & $1335$\\
$3$ & $0.007$ & $\hspace{5pt}0.0463$ & $47157$ & $\hspace{5pt}913$ \\
$4$ & $0.499$ & $\hspace{5pt}0.0127$ & $31937$ & $\hspace{5pt}589$
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Your `tabular` contains a number of math content that isn't inside `$`...`$`.

Comment: i try, not work

Comment: You should try harder... Hmmm, perhaps you can post the code as an edit to your question, rather than a picture of the code.

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code. Instead, post the code itself.

Comment: i poste code, help me please

Comment: For sure, all terms that involve `\frac`, `^`, and `_` *must* be in math mode.

Comment: i added edited code, not worked

Comment: @UFO102: The last piece of code contains a tabular specifying only 5 columns. However, you've inserted 6 column's worth of data. Remove the trailing `&` from each row.

Comment: @UFO102: As an aside, saying "it doesn't work" doesn't provide any clue for the solvers what you've tried or *where* the problem is. Be specific, please.

Comment: I edited the code. The table moves down, mistakes were

Comment: The new line `\\ ` or `\tabularnewline` ([Difference between \\ and \tabularnewline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78796/106162)) is needed at the end of each line of the tabular.

Comment: I fixed the table. But the problem is in the }

Comment: I fixed the table and added it at the end of your posting. There were still some `$` signs missing.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A number of issues:

- Use `$`...`$` for math content (this includes `\frac`, `^`, `_`, ...);
- Don't let `$`...`$` straddle an alignment character `&`;
- Consider using [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for the placement of units;
- Use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text` for text inside math mode;
- Consider using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for horizontal rules in your `tabular`;
- Be careful of spurious spaces. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)
- If you're resizing tables to make them fit, consider some alternatives. See [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}
\DeclareSIUnit{\calorie}{cal}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{This is a caption}
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c S[table-format = 1.3] S[table-format = 1.4] S[table-format=5.0] S[table-format=4.0]}
      \toprule
      No & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$D_a$, $\frac{\si{\cm}^2}{\si{\second}} \times 10^{-11}$} 
         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$D_{\mathrm{d}V}$, $\frac{\si{\cm}^{2}}{\si{\second}} \times 10^{-11}$} 
         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$H_{\mathrm{d}V}$, $\si{\calorie\per\mol}$} 
         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$T_{\text{eff}}, \si{\degree\kelvin}$} \\
      \midrule
      1 & 0.169 & 0.204  & 64610 & 1326 \\
      2 & 0.540 & 0.0633 & 68151 & 1335 \\
      3 & 0.007 & 0.0463 & 47157 &  913 \\
      4 & 0.499 & 0.0127 & 31937 &  589 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would not recommend `\text` for this as it is not stabe if the context is italic. Rather use `\textup ` or `\textnormal `, `\text` is very widely misused.