# tcolorbox & text vertically center align

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

tcolorbox and text does not vertically align to the center with one another.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}% for framed rounded boxes
\tcbset{colframe=black,colback=white,colupper=black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,nobeforeafter,center title,size=small}

\begin{document}

\tcbox{1}, \tcbox{2}, ... ,\tcbox{9} -- numbers\\
\tcbox{$+$}, \tcbox{$-$}, \tcbox{$\times$}, \tcbox{$\div$} -- operators\\
\tcbox{$(-)$} -- negative sign\\
\tcbox{$=$} or \tcbox{\sc{Enter}} -- equal sign\\

\end{document}
```

[image: text align]

As can be seen, the text is aligned to the bottom.
How do I make both of them align next to one another?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use the option `box align=base` (or `tcbox raise base`, which is equivalent) in your `\tcbset`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}% for framed rounded boxes
\tcbset{colframe=black,colback=white,colupper=black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,nobeforeafter,center title,size=small,box align=base}

\begin{document}

\tcbox{1}, \tcbox{2}, ... ,\tcbox{9} -- numbers

\tcbox{$+$}, \tcbox{$-$}, \tcbox{$\times$}, \tcbox{$\div$} -- operators

\tcbox{$(-)$} -- negative sign

\tcbox{$=$} or \tcbox{\sc{Enter}} -- equal sign

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

P.S. Don't use `\\` to start a new paragraph, but either a blank line or `\par`.

---

### EDIT

If you need this behavior only for some of the boxes, assign that property locally instead of globally. This means to remove the option from your `\tcbset` and set it for the boxes where it is needed, e.g.

```
\tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$(-)$}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}% for framed rounded boxes
\tcbset{colframe=black,colback=white,colupper=black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,nobeforeafter,center title,size=small}

\begin{document}

\tcbox[tcbox raise base]{1}, \tcbox{2}, ... ,\tcbox{9} -- numbers

\tcbox{$+$}, \tcbox{$-$}, \tcbox{$\times$}, \tcbox{$\div$} -- operators

\tcbox[tcbox raise base]{$(-)$} -- negative sign

\tcbox{$=$} or \tcbox{\sc{Enter}} -- equal sign

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the error: I do not know the key '/tcb/box align', to which you passed 'base', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you mispelled it.

Comment: What is the difference between \newline and \\?

Comment: @Eugene Try `tcbox raise base` instead of `box align=base`

Comment: @Eugene See [What is the difference between \newline and \\?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27028/27635). Anyway, I didn't mention `\newline` but `\par`.

Comment: I see, thanks. What if I want tcbox raise base for some text but not others?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218928/tcbox-raise-base-for-selected-text-only

Comment: @Eugene See the edit.