# Looking for an (old?) problem with \\

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

(No, I'm not looking for a solution. I'm really looking for a problem.)

I remember that, a long time ago, I encountered a situation where
the `\\` (newline) command would insert a *blank* line if the line
preceding the newline was already full. That is,

```
abc\\xyz
```

resulted in

> abc
>   xyz

as desired, but

```
this is a really long line reaching the right margin\\xyz
```

resulted in

> this is a really long line reaching the right margin
>
> xyz

instead of the desired

> this is a really long line reaching the right margin
>   xyz

At that time, I could fix the problem by using `\par\noindent` instead of `\\`
(which has of course other problems, in particular if parskip
or parsep are non-zero).
But I don't remember under which circumstances this happened,
which document class and which macro packages were used,
and in fact it may have even been old LaTeX instead of LaTeX2e.
The strange thing is: The problem has disappeared.
I cannot reproduce it anymore.

Does that ring a bell with anybody?
Are there any parameter settings that could give rise to such a
behavior?
Have there been any changes in the definition of `\\`
in the standard LaTeX packages (in particular, from old LaTeX to LaTeX2e)
that could explain it?

Comment: Well, just don't use ``\\`` for breaking lines. `;-)`

Comment: maybe you were in a table context ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077)

Comment: @egreg I *have* avoided ` \\ ` for ten years or so. But I wonder whether the reason why I started to avoid it has disappeared completely, or whether there is still some exceptional case where the lengthy `\par\noindent` may be more robust.

Comment: @percusse No, definitely not in a table. Perhaps in some list environment, but probably not even that.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behavior you claim to have seen. Most probably there was a space before ``\\``.

Comment: @egreg I can't reproduce it either (today), not even with spaces before or after ` \\ `. But I'm rather sure that I saw it ten or twenty years ago. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: This isn't the reason you should avoid using `\\ ` to break lines, even if it is the reason you have avoided it.

Comment: @cfr Do you object to (1) breaking lines at all, or to (2) using \\ to do it? If (1): I'm talking about things like lecture slides, where enforcing certain line breaks really improves readability, or about some kinds of data listings, like `\begin{itemize}\item a\\b\item c\\d\end{itemize}`. Not about ordinary aligned text in an article. If (2): What else do you suggest?

Comment: You shouldn't use `\\ ` to break lines. I assumed that was @egreg's point.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer’s answer is brilliant; but of course, you *can* reproduce the desired behavior only by means of spaces, as @egreg suggests, provided that you put at least *two* of them in a row in the horizontal list being formed, so that one of them survives the `\unskip` performed by `\@gnewline`.  For example, `word1 \ \\word2` will do.  See also: (1) `ltspace.dtx`, definition of `\@normalcr`; (2) _The TeXbook_, p. 97, fifth paragraph, end of first sentence, and (3) p. 114, last paragraph.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thanks a lot. I didn't think about two (protected) spaces.

Comment: @cfr So, what else should I use to break lines? (Or do you mean that I shouldn't put a space after \\ ?)

Comment: Maybe tomorrow I’ll turn my comment into an answer, if I feel so inclined… (I’m very lazy!  But the references I gave do contain the full explanation… :-)

Comment: No the space is just because SE gobbles the code without it.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-or-blank-lines http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/what-is-the-difference-between-newline-and etc.

Comment: `\par\noindent` is completely different to `\\ ` in both action and meaning so there is never really a choice between them. The author should know whether or not a paragraph is ending at that point.

Comment: @cfr I am familiar with the articles you refer to. They say that one *should*
use \\ to enforce a linebreak. (For the sake of discussion, you may assume
that I don't use \\ to end paragraphs, that I don't use \\ as a replacement for \linebreak[n], that I don't use \\ in the middle of ordinary running text in an article, and that I know when visual formatting is appropriate and when it's not.)

Comment: @Uwe can we also assume you've been using latex since about 1985? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that the first thing I wrote in LaTeX was my diploma thesis, so it must have been 1988.

Comment: @Uwe ooh only one year before `\\ ` was fixed for this issue then:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Given the maintenance of the LaTeX installation, I may still have encountered the problem in 1993 or so.

Comment: Well, Beamer is non-standard anyway as you are already typesetting non-justified text regardless.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have good memory, the change predates LaTeX2e but in the latex sources you find...

```
  \begin{macro}{\@gnewline}
 \changes{v1.2u}{1996/10/29}{Added macro}
 The |\nobreak| added to prevent null lines when |\\|
 ends an overfull line.  Change made 24 May 89 as suggested by
 Frank Mittelbach and Rainer Sch\"opf
```

Similarly in the final sources of latex2.09 (`latex.tex`)

```
% \nobreak added to \newline to prevent null lines when \newline
% ends an overfull line.  Change made 24 May 89 as suggested by
% Frank Mittelbach and Rainer Sch\"opf
%
\def\newline{\ifvmode \@nolnerr \else \unskip\nobreak\hfil
  \penalty -\@M\fi}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can get this if the word ends with a hyphen:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\textwidth=1mm
\begin{document}
margin-\\xyz
\end{document}
```

[image]