# newline command causes a small space in column

Tags: floats, line-breaking, subfloats, paragraphs

I want to present 4 figures inside one float, so I'm using the following format:
[image]

Although, when I present this float I get:
[image]

As you can see, there is a small vertical space between the first "line" to the other. I want the 4 figure to be aligned and symmetric.

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Note: the lyx file + latexpdf + pdf available in the comments.

Latex code:

```
% Preview source code for paragraph 0

\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{../Documents/MEGA/Technion/Msc/Thesis/Code/code_files/Thesis/images/edges_bias/original_PH}

}\hspace{1px}\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{../Documents/MEGA/Technion/Msc/Thesis/Code/code_files/Thesis/images/edges_bias/composed_PH}}\\\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{../Documents/MEGA/Technion/Msc/Thesis/Code/code_files/Thesis/images/edges_bias/original_PH}

}\hspace{1px}\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{../Documents/MEGA/Technion/Msc/Thesis/Code/code_files/Thesis/images/edges_bias/composed_PH}}
\par\end{centering}
\centering{}\caption{Description: (a) (b) (c) (d)}
\label{fig:filtering_process}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome, can you boil down your LyX document to just this and upload the lyx file? The exported pdflatex file would be great as well.

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to add files, but I can share this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3qnsDa7ZucCZVE1ZWZ6aksydmc

Comment: Please add the content of the files. They should be rather short, as everything else is removed. Open them with a simple text editor.

Comment: @Mico Just to be sure, i can see `\newline` in the screenshot. It is even in the title.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Ah, i had overlooked the newline string in the title! I still believe, though, that the OP ought to have made more of an effort to post the code in the query itself, to make it more accessible and user-friendly. If you believe the query merits re-opening, please go ahead.

Comment: I added the code. Sorry didn't do it before, I needed to check how :) (First time on lyx, after long years with Office Word XD)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess I solved it. I don't know why, but apparently using `\\` instead of `\newline` just solved the problem (didn't create the space).

The difference between `\` and `\newline` detailed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/what-is-the-difference-between-newline-and).

[image]

Thank you all anyway :)

Comment: This reads more like a comment than as a full answer.

Comment: You right, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself some favors:

1. Use a macro instead of repeating umpteen times a long path.
2. Don't rely on dubious sources for LaTeX code.
3. Don't use `\newline` or `\\` when not needed; by the way, `\newline` should never be used in a `\centering` context.
4. Don't use `px`, because you don't know how big it is.

The `centering` environment doesn't exist as such; there is the `\centering` *declaration*.

In the following example I used the `demo` option to `graphicx` because I don't have your images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newcommand{\figurepath}{%
  ../Documents/MEGA/Technion/Msc/Thesis/Code/code_files/Thesis/images%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{\figurepath/edges_bias/original_PH}}\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{\figurepath/edges_bias/composed_PH}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{\figurepath/edges_bias/original_PH}}\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{\figurepath/edges_bias/composed_PH}}

\caption{Description: (a) (b) (c) (d)}
\label{fig:filtering_process}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]