# how to do the line split

Tags: line, split

Please help on how to do the line split

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).`

Comment: Off-topic: `1+2+3=6`, no?

Comment: @Mico what a hairsplitter ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bare reproduction of the image you posted is

```
\noindent When $x=1$, $y=1,2,3,4$ \\
and $x = 2$, $y=1,2,3$ \\
$1+2+3=7$ pairs
```

My guess it that the commands you are looking for are `\\` or `\newline`, that tell LaTeX to start a new line.
For reference see [What is the difference between \newline and \\?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/what-is-the-difference-between-newline-and)

In a more complete way:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % for the font
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\noindent When $x=1$, $y=1,2,3,4$ \\
and $x = 2$, $y=1,2,3$ \\
$1+2+3=7$ pairs
\end{document}
```

Which returns

[image]

Comment: the preview should look like on the image I attached.

Comment: What differences do you think there are, still?

Comment: i dont know why the preview is different here

Comment: What do you mean by "here"? Where exactly is "here"? On your system, or on overleaf? In the answer I just put a screenshot of my output.
I strongly suggest you to show the effort of posting a MWE as I already pointed out in the first comment, so that we can work out the differences you still notice.
Otherwise your question is very likely to be closed (it has already been flagged) and that is how far you will get. The community can help you more with a MWE at hand.
There is a lot of people willing to help, but sometimes the information provided in the question is just not enough.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin - I think the OP may be focusing on the use of a Times-Roman math font.

Comment: Thanks Mico, I also think so; will we know?
However I can't guess the right font. It's not `mathptmx`, nor `mathpazo`. Do you have a better guess?
Anyway, the title says "how to split the line" ;)

Comment: I am using Mathjax Live Demo and when I pasted your solution it's not the same with your preview. I cant paste the image here so you will see what it look like.

Comment: @EdlynNavales - The screenshot you posted (a) doesn't insert whitespace after `x=1,` and `x=2,` respectively, and (b) inserts no whitespace at all after the commas in the expressions for `y`. I regard both issues as noticeable defects from a typographic/aesthetic point of view. Observe that Alessandro's solution doesn't exhibit either defect.