# Line break in a list

Tags: lists, line

The following image is the output from the following block of code:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item In the document, put: \textbackslash lipsum[1-2] \\
        [1-2] means generate paragraph from 1 to 2.
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

However, what I intend to produce is something that looks like:

```
•In the document, put:\lipsum[1-2]
 [1-2] means generate paragraph from 1 to 2
```

I'm confused of what went wrong and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: don't ignore error messages!  use `\\ \relax`  so the `[1...` isn't taken as the optional `\\[5pt]` length argument (and generate an error about missing length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Building on David's comment.
- **You can use `\\{}`.**
- For more background info see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091) (regarding `\\{}`) and
  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27028) (regarding `\\[5mm]`).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item In the document, put: \textbackslash lipsum[1-2] \\{}
        [1-2] means generate paragraph from 1 to 2.
    \item In the document, put: \textbackslash lipsum[1-2] \\[5mm] % You can also try "0mm" :)
        [1-2] means generate paragraph from 1 to 2.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]