# Move a few lines to the right of the page in the sheet

Tags: formatting

I would like to move a series of consecutive lines (`AAA-FFF`) to the right of the page, but I only move the first one (`AAA`). This is the LaTex source code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
\begin{document}
\hfill AAA \newline
\hfill BBB \newline
\hfill CCC \newline
\hfill DDD \newline
\hfill EEE \newline
\hfill FFF \\

\today \\

XXX \newline
YYY \newline
ZZZ \\

My text starts here...
\end{document}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to texexchange. It hasn't been that long since I signed up myself and I've already learned a lot. For your problem, I don't really know how to explain it , but it works.

With \null before the \hfill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to is align text to the right side of the page I would suggest the usage of `\raggedleft` as follows.

```
{\raggedleft
AAA \\
BBB \\
CCC \\
DDD \\
EEE \\
FFF \\
}
```

Please note that I changed `\newline` to `\\` since the usage of `\newline` would lead to undesired results.
You can read more on that topic [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/what-is-the-difference-between-newline-and).

Answer (score 3):

I describe the reason why only AAA is at the right margin. The `\newline` does (roughly speaking) `\nobreak\hfil\break`. You are using `\hfill` primitive at the left side. A text follows and then there is `\nobreak\hfil\break`. First line: `\hfill` is more stretchable than `\hfil` used in the `\newline` macro, so AAA is at the right margin. But the `\break` macro expands to `\penalty-10000` and it makes forced break of the line. Following "discardable items" are ignored by TeX. Your `\hfill` is a glue, so it is a discarable item. It is ignored. Next line includes only `BBB\nobreak\hfil\break` so the `BBB` is on the left side.